# Angular 2 Reactive Forms - Detect input change event on component

Tags: angular2-forms

I would like to detect the value of change event to the input on form.component.ts.
I would not like to call the function ex: (onChange) = "function($event.target.value)"

```
public form: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){ 

}

private loadForm(){
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        tipo: [null, Validators.required],
        nomeRazao: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(64)])],
        apelidoFantasia: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(64)])],
        cpfCnpj: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(11), Validators.maxLength(14)])],
        rgIe: [null],
        contato: this.formBuilder.group({
            email: [null],
            telefone: [null]
        }),
        endereco: this.formBuilder.group({
            cep: [null, Validators.pattern('^([0-9]){5}([-])([0-9]){4}$')],
            uf: [null],
            cidade: [null],
            bairro: [null, Validators.required],
            logradouro: [null],
            complemento: [null],
            numero: [null, Validators.pattern('/^\d+$/')]
        })
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.loadForm();
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For detecting changes in value of a particular field, 'valueChanges' event on that field can be subscribed, as shown below:

```
this.myForm.get('formcontrolname').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.message = val;
  });
```

Comment: Can you please tell a little bit more, Where to include this snippet?

Actually I have to detect the change of checkbox of dynamic form.

Comment: @SaurabhSinghRajput   put it in  ngOnInit()

Comment: Here is a good link on the subject, but as Tom Stickel mentions put it inside ngOnInit instead of ngOnChanges:  https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges

Answer (score 49):

You can subscribe to your form changes by using this :

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
   if (this.registerForm.controls['yourControlName'].value === 'someValue') {
      // 
   }
 });
```

Comment: good answer, but better type-safe would be:

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
   if (data.yourControlName === 'someValue') {
      // 
   }
 });

Answer (score 0):

For people who are checking for higher versions of Angular or to whom the accepted solution isn't working,

Try this

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
this.message = val.formcontrolname;});
```

the approach is to use the variables inside the change detection and you can restrict it with the respective form control name